# Difference between label address loading in x86 and x64

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, nasm, masm

I wrote a code in 64 bits linux, using NASM
    [bits 64]

```
section .text
global main
main:                  ; ELF entry point

mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, message       ; buffer
mov rdx, [messageLen]  ; length of buffer
syscall

mov rax, 60            ; sys_exit
mov rdi, 0             ; 0
syscall

ret

section .data
data1:  db 35,36,37

messageLen: dq message.end-message
message: db 'Hello 999  World!!!', 10
.end:
```

Now, In the

```
mov rax, message
```

the rax holds the address of "message" (eg 0x402044), similar to say doing something like this

```
lea rax, [message]
```

I looked into the disassembly and found that the code was executed as follows

```
movabs rax, 0x402044
```

Doing a mov reg, label command in 32 bit MASM just moved first data from the array that the label refers to

```
mov ax, label ; same as mov ax, [label]
```

So finally!!, my question here is **why does 32 bit load the data value while 64 bit loads the address?** Won't this create backward compatibility issues, if say I want to use a code written in 64bit in a 32 bit system?

I am very sorry if the question is very basic and/or trivial. I have been scratching my head over this for a few hours and don't quite get the logic behind two different implementations of loading labels. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit. It's a difference between two different assemblers.

In NASM, `mov eax, var` puts the address of `var` in `eax`. In MASM, the same code puts the content of `var` in `eax`.

To get the address of `var` in MASM, you need to use the `offset` operator:

```
mov eax, offset var
```

See also [this section](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2) of the NASM documentation which explains the difference.